# How do I do conditional tag rendering?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I render different JSX depending on the platform the user is running?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight, Platform, Text, Image } from "react-native";

export default class RoundButton extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
      const JSX = Platform.OS === "ios" ? <TouchableOpacity> : <TouchableHighlight>

        return (
            <JSX style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            </JSX>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this out once : https://kylewbanks.com/blog/how-to-conditionally-render-a-component-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code posted in question will also work with just minor change. Just remove those tags and use component name while performing the conditional operation.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Platform,
  Text,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

export default class RoundButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const JSX = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? TouchableOpacity : TouchableHighlight; // remove those tags and use simple Component name.

    return (
      <JSX onPress={() => alert('Hi')} style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{'Hi'}</Text>
      </JSX>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  buttonText: {},
});
```

Answer (score 1):

simply do this:

```
render(){
     if(Platform.OS === "ios"){
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity >
          );
      else{
          return (
            <TouchableHighlight style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight >
          );
      }
}
```

or this one:

```
   render(){

        const JSX = Platform.OS === "ios" ? <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text></TouchableOpacity > : <TouchableHighlight style={styles.container}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text></TouchableHighlight >

        return (JSX);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use `Ternary` operators

`render(){
     return(
          <View>
           { 
             Platform.OS === "ios" ?
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
             </TouchableOpacity > :
              <TouchableHighlight style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.title}</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight >
           }
          </View>
     )
}`